# weird result using EC_POINT_mul from OpenSSL

Tags: c++, openssl, diffie-hellman

I am trying to implement a Private Set Intersection (PSI) protocol that is based on the Diffie Hellman protocol.

The PSI protocol is the one mentioned in Section 2.2 of [[Kiss et al. 2017](http://eprint.iacr.org/2017/670)],,
there is already a Java implementation here:

https://github.com/encryptogroup/MobilePSI/blob/master/PSIServer/src/PSIDH.java

I want to implement it in C++, so I thought of using OpenSSL

## What I am trying to do

Here is roughly how it works:
let `G` be a generator for diffie hellman;
alice has a DH secret `a` and an element `x`,
bob has a DH secret `b` and an element `y`;
`h` is some function that takes any (bitstring) element and map it to an DH scalar.

- alice sends `G*a*h(x)` (call it *alice's side*)
- bob replies with `(G*a*h(x))*b` (call it *final alice's side*)
- bob sends `G*b*h(y)` (call it *bob's side*)
- alice computes `(G*b*h(y))*a`

Alice then compares both final values to learn whether `x == y` or not.

## The code

(minimal working example)

Using the fact that `G*a` is what is "Alice's public key" regarding Diffie-Hellman.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <openssl/obj_mac.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>

// list of possible curve names here:
// https://git.openssl.org/gitweb/?p=openssl.git;a=blob;f=crypto/objects/obj_mac.h;h=b5ea7cdab4f84b90280f0a3aae1478a8d715c7a7;hb=46ebd9e3bb623d3c15ef2203038956f3f7213620#l385
// also here:
// https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/67e247fad12308e34817e60c9242113c285fb00c/include/openssl/obj_mac.h#L261
#define CURVE_NAME NID_X9_62_prime256v1

class PSIEntity {
  public:
    BN_CTX* bn_ctx;
    const EC_GROUP* ec_group;
    EC_KEY* key;

    PSIEntity(BN_CTX* c, const EC_GROUP* g){
      bn_ctx = c;

      ec_group = g;
      key = EC_KEY_new();
      EC_KEY_set_group(key, ec_group);
      EC_KEY_generate_key(key);
    }

    EC_POINT* encode_and_mask(const unsigned char* x_data){
      BIGNUM* x = BN_bin2bn(x_data, 28, NULL);

      const EC_POINT* pubkey = EC_KEY_get0_public_key(key);
      EC_POINT* result = EC_POINT_dup(pubkey, ec_group);

      EC_POINT_mul(ec_group, result, x, NULL, NULL, bn_ctx);

      return result;
    }

    EC_POINT* mask(EC_POINT* p){
      EC_POINT* result = EC_POINT_dup(p, ec_group);
      const BIGNUM *priv_key = EC_KEY_get0_private_key(key);
      EC_POINT_mul(ec_group, result, priv_key, NULL, NULL, bn_ctx);

      return result;
    }
};



int main(){
  EC_GROUP *ec_group = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(CURVE_NAME);
  BN_CTX *bn_ctx = BN_CTX_new();

  PSIEntity alice(bn_ctx, ec_group);
  PSIEntity bob(bn_ctx, ec_group);

  // taken from "a_bin" in
  // https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography#Defining_Curves
  unsigned char x_data[28] =
          {0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
           0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFE,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
           0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFE};

  EC_POINT* alice_side = alice.encode_and_mask(x_data);
  EC_POINT* alice_side_final = bob.mask(alice_side);

  EC_POINT* bob_side = bob.encode_and_mask(x_data);
  EC_POINT* bob_side_final = alice.mask(bob_side);

  int final_points_are_different = EC_POINT_cmp(ec_group,
                                                alice_side_final, bob_side_final,
                                                bn_ctx);
  if(final_points_are_different==-1){
    std::cout << "comparison of final points failed" << std::endl;
  }else if(final_points_are_different==1){
    std::cout << "final points are different" << std::endl;
  }else if(final_points_are_different==0){
    std::cout << "final points are equal" << std::endl;
  }

  int temp_points_are_different = EC_POINT_cmp(ec_group,
                                                alice_side, bob_side,
                                                bn_ctx);
  if(temp_points_are_different==-1){
    std::cout << "comparison of temp points failed" << std::endl;
  }else if(temp_points_are_different==1){
    std::cout << "temp points are different" << std::endl;
  }else if(temp_points_are_different==0){
    std::cout << "temp points are equal" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

## Code Result and Problem

The result is:

```
final points are different
temp points are equal
```

I would expect the opposite:
final points should be equal because it's the same `x` on both sides

As to *"temp points are equal"*, this is very disturbing:
it means that we have `G*a*x == G*b*x` ?

If you compare `G*a` with `G*b` (the public keys) the answer is that they are different, so what seems to happen is that multiplication by `x` with `EC_POINT_mul` just "messes things up".

Any idea what is happening ?

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do the job. The problem is passing wrong parameters to `EC_POINT_mul()`. See [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/EC_POINT_mul.html) for documentation of `EC_POINT_mul()`.

```
EC_POINT* encode_and_mask(const unsigned char* x_data){
    ...
    EC_POINT_mul(ec_group, result, NULL, result, x, bn_ctx);

    return result;
}

EC_POINT* mask(EC_POINT* p){
    ...
    EC_POINT_mul(ec_group, result, NULL, result, priv_key, bn_ctx);

    return result;
}
```